# smb.conf's path and share_root in man 8 vfs_shadow_copy2

Tags: samba

I have read man pages for samba configuration (`smb.conf`) and for `vfs_share_copy2`. My aim is to study features of `vfs_share_copy2`. My main question is this: How `path` parameter of `smb.conf` relates to terms of `vfs_share_copy2 (8)` page? Am I right that "share_root" in `vfs_share_copy2` description is just another name for `path` parameter in `samba` configuration?

Links to man pages I mentioned above:

- [`vfs_share_copy2`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_shadow_copy2.8.html)
- [`smb.conf`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html)